# Why does Visual Studio 2010 have rendering problems in VMware?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, wpf-4.0

We were testing our WPF application on **Windows XP** in the **VMware Player** (with VMware Tools) and noticed that **dropdowns** were buggy in that all the choices would appear when you clicked on the ComboBox but as you moused over them they would **disappear**.

We then noticed that **Visual Studio Express 2010** has the exact **same problem** with its menus.

Here a menu item is **hanging** by itself in the middle of the screen:

[image]

Here a menu item is **stretched**:

[image]

We have WMware Tools installed:

[image]

We would definitely like to get our application to work without these bugs in VMware. **Has anyone experienced these problems and know if it is a problem with VMware, XP, WPF, or WPF 4.0?**

Comment: does the same problem occurr outside of VMware?

Comment: we develop our application on Windows XP with .net 3.5 and have never seen it, I used VS2010 with .NET 4 on Windows 7and have never seen it

Comment: I have the same problem in VMWare Player.

Comment: VMware Workstation 7 has just been released - does it fix any of these problems?

Comment: I'll check WMware Workstation 7, the above screenshots are from WMware Player 2.5.3 build-185404

Comment: WPF is probably doing stuff that is not supported by the VMware graphics driver...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and based on a VMWare support article http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1011709 I changed my graphics adapter from VMWare SVGA II to the default (native) Windows 7 driver.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: we solved it in a slightly different way: I installed VMware Workstation 7 which comes with its own VMware Player and when that loaded our machine, it offered to update our VMware Tools, which we did, which solved the above problem.

Comment: Both WPF and Silverlight appear to be slightly broken while running under VMWare Workstation, including v7 (I have XP as both host and quest). From what I can see, some mouse events are lost, which leads to quite bizarre behaviors (scrolling starting, but not ending, clicks not being registered)

Answer (score 0):

I read this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/10/14/hotfixes-available-for-scrolling-context-menu-problem.aspx) to install two patches for Visual Studio 2010 and WPF. This solves the problem.

Comment: It would be better if you describe contents of the page you have given link of.

Answer (score 0):

I've found problem with selection and scrolling during code editing.
Sometimes the text disappears and other times the selected text becomes unreadable.

If you turn of VMWare SVGA you can't resize the screen at any size.
I solved it enabling Aero themes (google for "install aero on windows 8").
Don't ask me how but it solves my problem.